# How to add a prefix-length index in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

As we known, there're prefix length column which can be added during index creation. For example in mysql,

```
alter table j1 add index idx_j1_str1 (str1(5));
```

I didn't find any equivalent solution in postgresql after I searched the google.com and stackoverflow.com.

Then can anyone tell me the answer except the function index in postgresql.

Any reply will be appreciated.

Comment: Since I have a table with column in mysql like this "str1 text, key idx_str1_prefix5 (str1(5))...". I want to migrate it to postgresql without any change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
create index idx_j1_str on j1 (left(str1,5));
```

But I don't think you need something like this in Postgres. An index on just `str1` is probably much more versatile. But of course this depends heavily on the queries you run - which you did not show us, so it's impossible to say what kind of index you really need.

To make use of a function based index in Postgres (and basically any other DBMS that supports them) your query needs to contain the same expression as you used in the index:

```
select *
from j1
where left(str1,5) = '1234'
```

will use the above index (if it makes sense, e.g. if the table is large enough and the condition reduces the overall result substantially).

If you create a regular index on that column:

```
 create index idx_j1_str on j1 (str1 varchar_pattern_ops);
```

then it can be used for something like:

```
select *
from j1
where str1 like '1234%'
```

(which is equivalent to `left(str1,5) = '1234'`) but it can *also* be used for:

```
select *
from j1
where str1 like '1234678%'
```

or any other prefix search using a wildcard.

Comment: Thanks. But I have to write query like this " where left(str1,5) = '...'", otherwise no index can be used.

Comment: @Moon_of_father: a query using `where left(str1,5)` **will** use the above index in Postgres, see my edit.